# Undefined path shows when trying to log in via email or username in Django

Tags: python, django

I am making a login page with Django to log in via either username or email.
I start a app users, in this app, I have customized the users/model.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

in my users/views.py, I have code to read input name="username"

```
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.db.models import Q
class CustomBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(Q(username=username)) | Q(email=username))
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except Exception as e:
            return None
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request,user)
            return render(request, 'index.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html',{})

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request,"login.html",{})
```

my templates/login.html

```
<form action="/login/" method="post" id="jsLoginForm" autocomplete="off">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='mymQDzHWl2REXIfPMg2mJaLqDfaS1sD5' />
<div class="form-group marb20">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input name="username" id="account_l" type="text" placeholder="username or email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group marb8">
     <label>Password</label>
     <input name="password" id="password_l" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" />
</div>
<div class="error btns login-form-tips" id="jsLoginTips"></div>
<div class="auto-box marb38">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="jsAutoLogin"> Auto login</label>
    <a class="fr" href="forgetpwd.html">forget pwd?</a>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-green" id="jsLoginBtn" type="submit" value="login > " />
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

in urls.py

```
from users.views import login
urlpatterns = [
    url('^login/$',login, name='login'),
]
```

in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
"django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
'users.views.CustomBackend',
]
```

As a result, I can log in using the username and password, it prints:

```
[03/Feb/2019 23:40:06] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37066 #
```

but when I log in with email and password, nothing change in my browser. On the terminal, it prints:

```
Not Found: /user/login/ 
[03/Feb/2019 23:41:30] "POST /user/login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2213
```

I don't know where this path "/user/login/" comes from, it's different from the one "/login/" before.

SOLVED:
I found the problem is caused by the codes I copy from the tutorial, there is a login.js including something like `$.ajax({ url:"/user/login/",}). And this happens when I use email to login.

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: @schillingt Added template and urls.py, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you verify where the POST is actually being sent to using the network panel in Chrome/Firefox dev tools? Everything looks right, so we need to step back a little bit further to eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: @schillingt the POST is sent to <http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/> in the network panel

Comment: just remove `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` and try

Comment: @toblKr did you tried what I said?

Comment: @Ahtisham Just tried but still the same problem.

Comment: inside this prototype `def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):` remove `request`

Comment: also add this line in your authenticate function `UserModel = get_user_model()` and then `user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(username=username)) | Q(email=username))`

Comment: @Ahtisham I found the problem is caused by the codes I copy from the tutorial, there is a `login.js` including something like `$.ajax({ url:"/user/login/",}). And this happens when I use email to login.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not using somewhere ...

```
url(r'user/',  include(users.urls))
```

and try to use the `{% url ... %}` tag for your form action attribute.

On the other hand, I think you should try to put your `CustomBackend` first on the list:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'users.views.CustomBackend',
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
]
```

You can read from the docs, that order matters:

> The order of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS matters, so if the same username and password are valid in multiple backends, Django will stop processing at the first positive match.
>
> **If a backend raises a PermissionDenied exception, authentication will immediately fail. Django won’t check the backends that follow.**

Maybe the default backend do not find the user (you're looking by email).

Comment: I changed it but doesn't help, the POST request still goes to `/user/login/`.

Comment: @toblKr Are you including your `users.urls` patterns some how?

Comment: My 'users.urls' is empty in this demo, only projects's url 'demo.urls' is involved.

Comment: I found the problem is caused by the codes I copy from the tutorial, there is a login.js including something like `$.ajax({ url:"/user/login/",}). And this happens when I use email to login.